# Custom syntax highlighting on TFS

Tags: git, tfs, syntax-highlighting, github-linguist

#### Scenario

In GitHub, we can use `.gitattributes` to set **linguist** directive in order to have  a custom detection for files with different extensions. We can also set the syntax directly in our files (`vim: syntax=clipper`). I'm migrating some projects from Bitbucket and SourceSafe to Visual Studio Online (TFS), but we'll keep git as the version control.

#### Problem

Apparently, there is not clear way to set a custom syntax for a different file. Where I work, we use a different language called *AdvPL*. *AdvPL* is very similar to Clipper and Foxpro, therefore, if TFS supports highlighting *xbase*, it should support highlighting `.prw`, `.ch` and `.prx` files.

#### What I've tried

- Putting a `.gitattributes` with several directives
- Putting vim directives inside the files
- Looking for custom settings in the repository
- Reading the Microsoft docs

Answer (score 1):

The library **Linguist** is used on **GitHub.com** to detect blob languages, ignore binary or vendored files, suppress generated files in diffs, and generate language breakdown graphs.

When use TFS, we always get the project/files from server to local, then work on them. TFS doesn't have linguist directive feature. You may use the tool which supports linguist directive to open the files.